# Webview delegate's shouldChangeSelectedDOMRange: called with document-fragment instead of full document

Tags: macos, cocoa, webkit

My web view has several  elements, which can be edited by the user to update model objects in the OS X host application.

For some of these  elements, when editing delegate methods like `webView:shouldChangeSelectedDOMRange:toDOMRange:affinity:stillSelecting:` are called, the range arguments are inside a #document-fragment container -without any attribute information at all.

Thus, it is nearly impossible to figure out, what node is being edited - as all id attributes have been stripped.

```
po proposedRange.commonAncestorContainer.path 
/#document-fragment/DIV/DIV/DIV/#text
```

For other input elements, I get the whole DOM path, with all attribute information intact:

```
po proposedRange.commonAncestorContainer.path
/#document/HTML/BODY/DIV/DIV/DIV/TABLE/TBODY/TR/TD/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/TABLE/TBODY/TR/TD/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/DIV/H1/SPAN/#text
```

Any ideas what could cause this difference in behavior?